# t-SNE generates different results on different machines

Tags: python, macos, ubuntu, scikit-learn, dimensionality-reduction

I have around 3000 datapoints in 100D that I project to 2D with t-SNE. Each datapoint belongs to one of three classes. However, when I run the script on two separate computers I keep getting inconsistent results. Some inconsistency is expected as I use a random seed, however one of the computers keeps getting better results (I use a macbook pro and a stationary machine on Ubuntu).

I use the t-SNE implementation from Scikit-learn. The script and data is identical, I've manually copied the folder to make sure. The relevant code snippet looks like this:

```
X_vectors, X_labels = self.load_data(spec_path, sound_path, subset)
tsne = TSNE(n_components=2, perplexity=25, random_state=None)
Y = tsne.fit_transform(X_vectors)
self.plot(X_labels, Y[:, 0], Y[:, 1], Y)
```

The first image is one sample generated from the macbook, I've ran it several times and it always generates a similar shape within the same x/y-range. The second is from Ubuntu and is clearly better, again I've ran it several times to make sure and it continues to generate better results, always in a higher x/y-range compared to the mac. Not sure what I'm not seeing here, it may very well be something obvious that I missed.

[image: Result from the MacbookPro]
[image: Result from Ubuntu]

Comment: Please use same integer value (not `None`) for random_state on both machines and then report the variations.

Comment: It returns similar results as before. The reason I used None was to make sure that the fixed seed didn't have anything to do with it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

TSNE is a heuristic. Like most heuristics, it might behave quite differently according to small changes. The core characteristic here is: only local-convergence is guaranteed! (not very robust). The latter is indicated (follows from basic optimization-theory) in the [docs](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.manifold.TSNE.html):

> t-SNE has a cost function that is not convex, i.e. with different initializations we can get different results.

While you explained, that the non-seeding approach is not the culprit in your opinion (hard to measure! benchmarking is hard), **you should check out your versions of sklearn**, as the [t-sne code](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/commits/18317f2bd39b77744779ede848eec2c95c5ff590/sklearn/manifold/t_sne.py) is one of the more active parts of sklearn with many changes over time.

Each of these changes is likely to introduce observations like yours (when only trying one example; a bigger benchmark/testset should be a better approach when comparing t-sne implementations of course)

Remark: `however one of the computers keeps getting better results:` this is broad as there are at least two different interpretations:

- rate the result visually / perceptually
- look at `kl_divergence_` achieved after optimization

Comment: A version update fixed it! The macbook had version 0.18.2 before, now both are 0.19 and they generate identical results given a fixed seed. Thank you.I agree that a "better result" is relative in this scenario, I was referring to non-overlapping clusters.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation!